# Can we use Cloudformation to define a social provider for Cognito UserPool?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I just successfully went through the Cognito setup through AWS console, which is a manual process. I wanted to code it up next, i.e.,

I wanted to setup and configure my Cognito with Cloudformation config file [AWS AWS::Cognito::UserPool](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html). However, I don't see a field that define the open id connect providers (i.e, the Facebook and Google as identity provider).

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am on the Cognito team and this is not possible at this point. However, it is on our roadmap to bring CloudFormation support up to speed to all the features we have launched recently.

Comment: Are we any closer to this now?

Comment: any update on this?